# Django expected string or buffer in json loads

Tags: php, django, json, urllib

So i am getting a `expected string or buffer` in django when i try to parse a Json string sent from a php source to django client using urllib to fetch the request.
I am using a celery task also.

The string is:

```
"511bd5112aa8c"
```

Php:

```
echo json_encode($access_token);
```

Django:

```
from celery import task
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError

@task()
def replicate_data(req):
        try:
            response = urlopen(req)
            the_page = response.read()
        except URLError:
            raise replicate_data.retry(countdown=15)

        return the_page



result=replicate_data.apply_async((req,), queue='rep_data')
json.loads(result)
```

i have already tried `json.loads(result.decode())` with no luck also.

anyone?

Comment: Do you have an example of the type of string you are trying to pass?

Comment: and, if possible, may you show us where "result" variable is defined

Comment: this is my string 511bd5112aa8c

Comment: updated with more info

Comment: Is your string `511bd5112aa8c` or `"511bd5112aa8c"` ? The quotes around it will be important, and should be in the actual output, to make it valid JSON

Comment: with the suggestion in the answer i now have this json {"token":"511bd95c10116"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is fine. The trouble is with how you're trying to use it.

Celery is a mechanism to perform computation asynchronously. When you call

```
result=replicate_data.apply_async((req,), queue='rep_data')
```

That's not the same thing as just calling a function. You are sending data off to a queue to be processed some time later by the function.

`apply_async` doesn't, and *can't* return the value that the function computes. Instead, what it returns is an [AsyncResult object](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html), which contains lots of details about where and how the task is going to be handled.

If you want to do something with the JSON that you get from the page, you have to do it from *inside* the task. The code that queues the task is simply never going to see that return value.

For testing only, you can call the task synchronously, with `apply`. This will return an `EagerResult` object, but you can get the function return value from that, since it causes your code to block until the function returns. That would look like this:

```
result=replicate_data.apply((req,), queue='rep_data')
return_value = result.return
json.loads(return_value)
```

But I would really only advise that for testing / debugging, since it completely nullifies the advantage that celery's asynchronous processing gives you.

Answer (score 0):

It is invalid json. Try using some node name and assign that token as value to have the valid json. Now json.loads will work fine.

```
<?php
$access_token = "511bd5112aa8c";
echo json_encode(array("token"=>$access_token));
?>
```

Edit:

Use the above mentioned code of php. And for python use this:

```
json_res = json.loads('{"token": "511bd5112aa8c"}')     
print json_res['token']
```

Replace the text in json.loads with the response variable.

Comment: A string is perfectly valid JSON -- but it has to be quoted.

Comment: I was not considering quotes in my explanation.

Comment: this is my json now {"token":"511bd95c10116"}

Comment: i did this json_res = json.loads(result)  print json_res['token'] and i still get the same error :(

Comment: I feel that using result=replicate_data.apply_async((req,), queue='rep_data') data is sent asynchronously because of which other part of code is getting executed before the response get assigned to result.